# Remove ul(no id for ul) elements from a class - Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to develop a greasemonkey script that removes a bar from a site, so far, I've maganged to remove the class itself, but I cannot remove the content within the div. I can remove all ul elements in the entire site, but I only need to remove all specific elements associated with "bar" div class and the ul inside doesn't have an ID, so I can't track it by JQuery. How do I remove the elements ?

```
<div class="bar"> <ul>
                    <a href="..." onclick=""/>
    <span class="title">Title 1</span>
    </a>

     <a href="..." onclick=""/>
    <span class="title">Title 2</span>
    </a></ul></div>
```

This is what I have so far in JQuery

```
$(".bar").removeClass('bar');
```

I've tried this, but it removes all the UL elements in the entire page and I don't want that

```
$('ul:not(:first):not(:last)').remove();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want this:

```
$(".bar ul").remove();
```

`jQuery('ancestor descendant')` [**docs**](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)

> Description: Selects all elements that are descendants of a given ancestor.

Comment: @cpx. Cool, don't forget to accept an answer, it's being done with the "check" sign near the answer you want to accept.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$(".bar > ul").remove();
```

---

Nevermind, `$(".bar ul").remove();` will work just as well.

Comment: Why did you use the `direct child(>)` selector?

Comment: @gdoron: I wasn't sure just the plain `$(".bar ul")` would work (it's cool that it's so simple), so I Googled and found this: http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/